# python bottle framework maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, html, bottle, sqlitestudio

I am trying to add a path for my web app but for some reason maximum recursion depth error occurs

```
def runSQL(sql):
    db = sqlite3.connect('zadanie.db')
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(sql)
    data = c.fetchall()
    db.commit()
    c.close()
    return data  

def Subjects(): 
    sql = "SELECT (here is my query)" 
    data = runSQL(sql) 
    return data

@app.route('/subjects')
def Subjects():
    sub = template('look4.html', rows=Subjects())              
    return sub
```

I have tried to set recursion limit to higher number, but then error segmentation fault 11 occurs.
I would be grateful for any debugging suggestions :)

Comment: You define `Subjects` two times, so you override the `Subjects()` function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem,uuuh indeed! i didn't notice that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the recursion *depth*. As you can see you define two functions named `Subject`.

As a result Python will *override* the first one with the second. Now the second one has a call to (what you think is) the previous one. But since `Subjects` is overriden, it will redirect to that function again so:

```
@app.route('/subjects')
def Subjects():
    sub = template('look4.html', rows=Subjects())
    return sub
```

Will get stuck in infinite recursion. The solution is to simply rename one of the two (probably it is better to rename the first one), and change the call, like:

```
def subjects_query(): 
    sql = "SELECT (here is my query)" 
    data = runSQL(sql) 
    return data

@app.route('/subjects')
def subjects():
    sub = template('look4.html', rows=subjects_query())              
    return sub
```

Also the convention is that functions in Python are lowercase with underscores, so you better rename the second one to `subjects` (like I have done here).